# Regex to match 000001 to 002000

Tags: regex

I have strings from <strike>000001</strike> 00000 to 999999.

I'm looking for a regex to capture the 2000 elements, from 000001 to 002000. Maybe the question is too naïve, but after some attemps, I'm not finding the right one...

Could somebody help, please? Thanks!

**EDIT:** this question has been identified as possible dublicated of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions) and I have asked to edit the question to explain why it isn't. The aforementioned question is about regex in general but I'm asking for a very specific case (you can argue if the specific case is trivial or not, but that is a different question ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Comment: It would probably be better to convert this to a number and compare... regex _can_ do this, but it's not ideal.

Comment: @Biffen this is not really a duplicate as he is asking for a particular scenario

Comment: specify input and expected output?

Comment: I have tried for instance with `E00(001\d\d\d|2000)` but is not working properly... I'm keep trying, just asking in the case somebody could help. In the case I find the right answer, I'll self-answer myself.

Comment: https://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html – but it's not pretty.

Comment: @JuanCarlosRodriguez The linked question is used as a duplicate for all the ‘I need a regex’ questions.

Comment: I'm not sure this should be closed with a so wide QA. The approach isn't 100% trivial (but there might be an existing closer QA).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this one:

```
^0*(2000|1?[0-9]{3})$
```

As per your comment, you also want to exclude "000000". Then use

```
^(?!000000)0*(2000|1?[0-9]{3})$
```

```js
["000000", "000001", "999999", "001541", "000015", "002000"].forEach(s=> console.log(s, /^(?!000000)0*(2000|1?[0-9]{3})$/.test(s)))
```

But most real world sane solutions would just parse the number and compare it to a range. This would be less prone to errors and much easier to check and maintain.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! However, as far as I understand, that regex would match 000000... Note the range to cover is from 000001 to 002000

Comment: @fgalan 000000 was excluded from the list of possible inputs in your question

Comment: @fgalan In any case I edited to exclude it in the regex

Comment: My fault, sorry. I have edited the post to explain that 000000 is also parte of the range. Thanks again for your feedback!

Comment: I'd switch the order of lookahead and start-of-the-line in your second regex for a minimal performance boost for non-matching cases.

Comment: @SebastianProske if input strings are always 6 chars long then there's probably no impact but I agree it can only be better.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:
`^00([01]\d{3}|2000)$`

Be careful, it also matches 000000, but as you said there's no such string so everything is ok.